# Creating Action Links With Special Characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I'm trying to create an action link which has a url parameter with a period. I can do this the following way:

```
        <a href="/@(tab)Profile/Index?selected=@(tab)&DatingProfile.ProfileId=@(Model.DatingProfile.ProfileId)" selectedTab=@tab>@tab</a>
```

yet, I can't do it with an ActionLink:

```
        @Html.ActionLink(tab, String.Format("{0}Profile", tab), new{selected=tab,DatingProfile.Id=Model.DatingProfile.ProfileId}, {selectedTab = tab})
```

I get the following compilation error:
**CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.**

Any ideas how I can get this to work with an Action Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous types, that used in ActionLink method for route parameters don't allow names with '.' character - it's C# feature - you can't change this. But you can use next:

```
@Html.ActionLink(tab, string.Format("{0}Profile", tab), new RouteValueDictionary { { "selected", tab }, { "DatingProfile.ProfileId", Model.DatingProfile.ProfileId } }, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "selectedTab", tab } })
```